# Elasticsearch search templates

Tags: json, templates, elasticsearch

I tried using ES's search template to do a conditional clause as specified [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html). I'm sending my request to the /[my_index]/_search/template endpoint. The request fails because of JSON parsing issues, which makes sense because after adding the conditional clause the payload is no longer a valid JSON. How than am I supposed to use the search templates? Is there a designated endpoint for non-JSON templates?

Comment: Have you tried storing the template as file in the `config/scripts` directory? See [pre-registered templates in the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#_pre_registered_template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the template in wrapping string.

From the same link you referenced:

> As written above, this template is not valid JSON because it includes
>   the section markers like {{#line_no}}. For this reason, the template
>   should either be stored in a file (see the section called
>   “Pre-registered templateedit”) or, when used via the REST API, should
>   be written as a string:
>
> "template":
>   "{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"line\":\"{{text}}\"}},\"filter\":{{{#line_no}}\"range\":{\"line_no\":{{{#start}}\"gte\":\"{{start}}\"{{#end}},{{/end}}{{/start}}{{#end}}\"lte\":\"{{end}}\"{{/end}}}}{{/line_no}}}}}}"

Comment: Excuse for a bump, but this doesn't work, still get bad request because of invalid json from Elastic. Using 1.7

Comment: Fixed in v2.0.0 it seems.

Answer (score 2):

When using conditional clauses,the template will not be a valid JSON because it will include the section markers  {{# like this }}.For this reason, the template should either be stored in a file or, when used via the REST API, should be written as a string.

Method 1 : tempalte stored in a file

1. Save the query part of the template in config/scripts

   ES installation>Config>scripts

   test_template.mustache

   ```
   {
       "query":{ whatever query }
   }
   ```
2. you can use the saved template by this method through sense

   ```
   GET /_search/template
   {
       "template": "test_template",
       "params": {
           whatever params
       }
   }
   ```

Method 2: template written as a string

1. convert the template to string form and use via rest api

   POST /_search/template/test_template
   {
       "template": "{\"query\":{ whatever query; remember to escape quotes}}"
   }
2. To search using this template,

   GET /_search/template
   {
       "template": {
           "id": "test_template" 
       },
       "params": {
           whatever params
       }
   }

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-template.html#_conditional_clauses